What does 貴重 mean in this context?
From おとなりに銀河 chapter 7:

She is looking for a place to work as a mangaka assistant and complained about not getting hired.
I am not sure about the meaing of 貴重 in this sentence:

しかしアナログでこの近辺の先生は貴重なのに

I think it means something like scarce?

This 貴重 means "precious", "scarce" or "rare and valuable". You may be misunderstanding not the word 貴重 itself but the other parts of the sentence or the context?

しかしアナログでこの近辺の先生は貴重なのに…
But mangaka who use analog methods and live around here are scarce/precious/rare...

She's saying that, although there are many mangaka in Japan, most of them either live far away or work digitally, making it impossible for her to work as an assistant.

Oh I see, thanks. It looks like an application of basic propositional logic... Let P="use analog methods" and Q="live nearby." There are few mangakas that are P and Q, which implies there are lots of mangakas that are (not P) or (not Q).
